# C# Unity trying to figure out how to use Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have the following code...

```
StartCoroutine(GetSuggestions());

IEnumerator GetSuggestions() {
    longExecutionFunction(); // this takes a long time
    yield return null;
}
```

How can I use a coroutine to keep the main program flow going? Currently when it reaches longExecutionFunction(); the program stops for a few seconds. I'd like it if the whole program would keep working while this is going on. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Without using threads, assuming you can modify `longExecutionFunction`, and it looks something like this:

```
void longExecutionFunction()
{
    mediumExecutionFunction();
    mediumExecutionFunction();
    while(working)
    {
        mediumExecutionFunction();
    }
}
```

You could modify it to look like:

```
IEnumerator longExecutionFunction()
{
    mediumExecutionFunction();
    yield return null;
    mediumExecutionFunction();
    yield return null;
    while(working)
    {
        mediumExecutionFunction();
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Then modify the calling code something like:

```
StartCoroutine(GetSuggestions());

IEnumerator GetSuggestions() {
    yield return longExecutionFunction();
    //all done!
}
```

This would then do one "medium length thing" per update, keeping the game from hanging. If, and how finely you can break up the work inside `longExecutionFunction` depends on your code inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to start longExecutionFunction in another thread. You may want to look at this article to read about threading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx

Code Example:

```
var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() => {
    longExecutionFunction();
}));
thread.Start();
```

If you aren't familiar with threads you should read up on them before using them. :)

Comment: Unity game engine is not thread safe and it is strongly recommended to not use threads

Comment: Is this not doable with a coroutine?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) combined with a coroutine.

```
StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine());

[...]

IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        longExecutionFunction();
    });

    thread.Start();

    while (thread.IsAlive) yield return 0;

    // ... Use data here
}
```

However you cannot use any unity-objects or methods inside the `longExecutionFunction`, because unity is not thread safe. So you need to calculate all your data inside the `longExecutionFunction` and initialize unity objects when the method has returned.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot create threads in web player, so even if `longExecutionFunction()` didn't touch unity objects it would still restrict the platform.

Comment: @MikeMcFarland http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/76087-WebPlayer-Multi-threading This links tells something else.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the correction. It's good to know its possible.